# get or session?

Tags: php, session, get

i have a login form, which is in login.php. after authorization i moove client to some.php file! so, from following two methods, which is better?

1. i can send information aboud user `id` e.t.c by `GET`
2. i can use `SESSION` - s for this

what is more preferred?

and two words about why i ask this question.
i hear somewhere that `SESSION`s aren't good programing method, and it's not suggested to use them in such situations...

thanks

Comment: Which is better for **what**?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel just for storing user data

Comment: you can't store user data in the GET. Because GET is the HTTP method.

Comment: yes, you're true, but i can send it by get, and save it there during all operations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sessions are indeed the preferred solution. You can't trust data sent in the querystring ($_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE etc) because all of those can be changed by the user, but you can trust the that noone has tampered with the $_SESSION data since $_SESSION is stored on the server.

Comment: yes - the best way is to save the user id in your session, and if possible, save id hashed (aes) - but is not really important. Because if you save it in your session, the user cannot change it. and if he logs out. If you use $_GET, he can change "?id=1232" (e.g.) with "?id=1", and this maybe is an Administrator. Same in cookie and Post...

Comment: @ahmet2106: AES is an encryption scheme, not a hash function. For hashing, use SHA-512 or similar.

Comment: @Felix King, was my fault, i was meaning encryp :) Not hash^^ Yes for hash he can use sha or other...

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently bad about sessions. In fact, in this situation I would store the userid in the session rather than passing it around in the URL. It'll be much cleaner, and more professional, IMHO. Storing trivial information in the session is fine.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` might have its flaws, but using `$_GET` for this kind of thing is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right, then none. Use `POST` for this instead and then create `SESSION` upon logging in.

Let's say user comes to `index.php` where is login form. He fills in info and push "login". You send the data to `login.php` using `POST`. If the user name, password and whatever other information is correct, you create `SESSION` and redirect user somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SESSION if you want to store some information, that is based on the authentication success. Data in GET, POST variables is too easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to decide between $_SESSION and $_GET, then, for secure stuff, use $_SESSION. All the user can do with sessions is destroy them (by deleting the PHPSESSID cookie), but the user cannot manipulate them.

If you have to pass information once, $_SESSION is very good. You can store some data into the $_SESSION variable, change location via PHP (so the user cannot block the script by means of disabling JavaScript. Just use `header('Location: '.$path);`), use the $_SESSION content on the other page and the user does not have a time interval when he could destroy the session. This is safe.

Comment: No, it's not always safe. The user can refuse to follow the location header and don't do the second request, so you can't always trust that the user will do the second request after a location header (you can trust it if it's a legitimate user, but it's the illegitimate users we are trying to protect us from in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

The safest way would be to use SESSIONS because that would mean that only a token|identifier is stored on the client side, and all of the data represented by the token|identifier is stored on the server. Besides you can set expiry time for sessions too, that would make it more secure.

Answer (score 0):

`SESSION` is the best solution . Which makes more secure one  .User cant alter any of his data